# Ant: compile classes depending on property

Tags: ant, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get Ant to compile only parts of my project depending on a property (`module`) I set in the properties file. This is my first "real" interaction with ant so please bear with me :).

I don't want to create multiple targets because *the only thing* that differs between modules in the build process is the number of classes that are being compiled and some resources.

Now, here's my compile target:

```
<target name="compile.classes" depends="init" description="compile the source">
    <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${lib}"/>

    <copy todir="${classes}">
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <patternset refid="resources"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <echo message="${classes}"/>

    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${classes} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}">
        <!-- Conditions for compiling the separate modules -->
        <classpath refid="libs"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

What I want to have are some conditionals based on the value of the `module` property I've already set. Something like:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}">
    <if>
        <equals arg1="${module}" arg2="gpl" />
        <then>
            <patternset refid="gpl-classes"/>
        </then>
        <elseif /> <!-- etc -->
    </if>
</javac>
```

Although I've installed ant-contrib fine (I've tested the if tag somewhere else with a simple echo and it worked) it doesn't let me place if conditionals inside `javac` tags. Also, it doesn't let me place them inside `patternset` tags.

Is there any way I can condition what classes I compile depending on a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the file sets can be catered for by means of reference ids.

Essentially you

- define a `patternset` with `id` for each of the sets of sources associated with modules
- select the `patternset` to use by means of a property value in a `patternset` with `refid`

Here's an illustration:

```
<patternset id="pattern1">
    <include name="*1.txt" />
</patternset>

<patternset id="pattern2">
    <include name="*2.txt" />
</patternset>

<property name="pattern_choice" value="pattern2" />

<mkdir dir="dest" /> 
<delete dir="dest" /> 

<copy todir="dest">
    <fileset dir=".">
        <patternset refid="${pattern_choice}" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

By changing the value of property `pattern_choice` the set of files copied is changed.  You can set this in your properties file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want conditional logic functionality, you may use antcontrib library, specifically its **[if task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html)**.

Then you can do something like this:

```
<if>
  <equals arg1="${module}" arg2="gpl" />
  <then>
    <path id="javac.classpath">
      <path refid="libs"/>
      <path refid="gpl-classes"/>
    </path>
  </then>
  <else>
    <path id="javac.classpath" refid="libs"/>
  </else>
</if>

<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}">
  <classpath refid="java.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

Comment: Your example didn't work for me. Even though `javac.classpath` was set to point to a `<path>` that included a fileset with all the files I needed, it kept compiling the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use [MacroDef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html)